# Having trouble graphing values of x<0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

This is prefaced by saying that I have at most 3 hours of experience in Mathematica, so please treat me gently.  Anyways, my problem is that I'm trying to plot g(x) from x=-3 to x=3 and it seems to only want to display values of x>0
I've uploaded images of my inputs and what Mathematica is giving me.

I'm assuming the trouble is coming about because g(x) has a non-differentiable point a x=0, but even when I set the domain to x[-3,-1] and avoid zero entirely it still makes a graph with x[0,1] and doesn't even plot anything.  Help please?

[image: This is my g(x)]

[image: Attempting to plot g(x)]

[image: Attempt to force negative x values]

Comment: `Table[g[x], {x, -3, 3}] // N` shows that results for `x < 0` are imaginary.

Answer (score 6):

The function in question is not real valued at negative x, so naturally `Plot` fails to graph the negative portions. If you intended for `x^(2/3)` to be the square of the real cube root of x, then you can explicitly request that with:

```
g[x_] := CubeRoot[x]^2/(1+x+x^4);
```

As an additional note, general real odd roots are provided by the `Surd` function, e.g. `g[x_] := Surd[x,3]^2/(1+x+x^4)`.

Comment: I'm able to get a graph on my TI-89 of this function for values less than zero, what's it doing differently?

Comment: @Alex - Mathematica generally operates in the complex plane. Your calculator doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`x^(2/3)` can be real or complex for negative x.  Try

```
Plot[Re[g[x]], {x, -3, 3}]
```